# Memory limit hit: optimize code for finding twin primes

Tags: performance-tuning, prime-numbers

I need some help optimizing a Mathematica code so that it'll not max out RAM. Here's the code:

**Cell 1**

```
twinPrimesQ[tp_] := 
  tp[[1]] + 2 == tp[[2]] && PrimeQ[tp[[1]]] && PrimeQ[tp[[2]]];
primesList[p_] := Module[{out = {Prime[3]}, i},
   For[i = 4, Prime[i] <= p, i = i + 1,
    out = Append[out, Prime[i]];
    ];
   out
   ];
testPrime[p_, pl_] := 
  Module[{out, found = False, twinPrimes, primeFactors, 
    primeFactorsPowers, i},
   twinPrimes = {
     {3 5 prod p - 4, 3 5 prod p - 2},
     {3 5 prod p + 2, 3 5 prod p + 4}
     };
   primeFactors = primesList[p];
   primeFactorsPowers = Tuples[Range[0, pl], primeFactors // Length];
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[primeFactorsPowers], i = i + 1,
    out = 
     twinPrimes /. 
      prod -> Product[
        primeFactors[[k]]^primeFactorsPowers[[i]][[k]], {k, 1, 
         primeFactors // Length}];
    found = twinPrimesQ[out[[1]]] || twinPrimesQ[out[[2]]];
    If[found, Break[]];
    ];
   If[found, out~Select~(twinPrimesQ[#] &) // First, False]
   ];
```

**Cell 2**

```
testPrime[109, 1]
```

**Cell 3**

```
out = List[]; For[j = 30, j <= 30, j = j + 1, 
out = out~
   Append~{j, Prime[j], testPrime[Prime[j], 1]}]; out // TableForm
```

The code returns the first twin prime found that fits `{3 5 prod p - 4, 3 5 prod p - 2}, {3 5 prod p + 2, 3 5 prod p + 4}` where $p$ is a product of primes between 3 and the first input in cells 2 and 3.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Where the memory maxes out is when I enter 'testPrime[113, 1]` for cell 2, or `i = 29, i <= 29` in cell 3 for the 29th prime, 113. I can even have cell 3 run 'i = 4, i <= 28` with no issues, but for some reason it can't do the 29th prime or above without maxing out memory. I'm thinking there may be a way to have it run cell 2 in a fragmented manner where each prime product `p` is run independently, spits out a true or false for whether it creates a twin prime, then checks the next. Perhaps then a memory limit can be set on each individual fragment?

Comment: Here's a link to the Mathematica Notebook: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/TwinPrimes.nb

Comment: maybe instead of storing the primes in full form, store n where Prime[n] is the prime you are interested in.

Comment: But I think the multiplying out is the memory killer. Just have Prime[n] and Prime[n+1], where Prime[n] + 2 == Prime[n+1], and do division tests using Mod for the list of factors you require

Comment: forgive me if I have a poor understanding of what your code does

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G No, I think your suggestion makes sense. I'm actually not fully sure the steps it takes to get the result, but only what I input and what it spits out as someone else wrote it on Math StackExchange. You seem to get it from what I see. I'll suggest it to the writer and see if he'll do it up for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rewritten version. I hesitate to call it optimised as I suspect there are significant further improvements that could be made.

The major change is to remove the `Tuples` bit (which was using all the memory) and replace it with a call to `IntegerDigits` inside the loop. I also changed the way `prod` is computed, using the `Listable` attribute of `Power` and also replacing `Product` with `Times`.

There are a couple of other tweaks, but nothing important for performance. I replaced `For` with `Do`. I prefer `Throw` & `Catch` over `Break`, and I added a maximum number of iterations for the loop, to avoid silliness.

I also altered `primesList` to make use of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute of `Prime`.

```
twinPrimesQ[{a_, b_}] := a + 2 == b && PrimeQ[a] && PrimeQ[b];

primesList[p_] := Prime@Range[3, PrimePi@p]

testPrime[p_, pl_] := 
  Module[{twinPrimes, primeFactors, n, prod, maxiters = 10^7}, 
   twinPrimes = {{3 5 prod p - 4, 3 5 prod p - 2}, {3 5 prod p + 2, 3 5 prod p + 4}};
   primeFactors = primesList[p];
   n = Length[primeFactors];
   Catch[Do[
     prod = Times @@ (primeFactors^IntegerDigits[i, pl + 1, n]);
     If[twinPrimesQ[#], Throw[#]] & /@ twinPrimes,
     {i, Min[(pl + 1)^n - 1, maxiters]}]]];


(* example *)

testPrime[Prime[100], 5]
(* {26993431542303411984765525701, 26993431542303411984765525703} *)
```

Comment: YOU...ARE...AWESOME! This is sick! If this becomes useful, I'll credit you!

Comment: Couple thoughts... Elsewhere it's been mentioned, "The product of all twin primes is an even perfect square minus 1. Any factor (prime or not) less than the square root of X^2 - 1 eliminates the composite as a candidate. Furthermore, these factors are usually trivial - that is, they're found long before X.
Demonstration: http://www.naturalnumbers.org/TwinPrimeCalc.xlsm" Don't know what the code uses to check, but this may be handy.

Comment: Also, I added this to a cell at the bottom, and look out! 8000 different twin prime pairs all mapped to a single prime! EPIC! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/8000%20twin%20primes.txt

Comment: Also, how about an option to run a set number of threads each testing a separate prime?

Comment: One more request... How about another cell at the bottom that would list all matching twin primes for a prime input rather than stopping at the first.

Comment: You should be able to use testPrime in parallel, e.g. `ParallelTable[testPrime[Prime[j], 1], {j, 4, 1000}]

Comment: Checking *all* possible products would rapidly become impractical. For the m'th prime the number of products to check is `(pl+1)^(m-3)`, for example in `testPrime[Prime[100],1]` you would be testing 2^97 products. I'm getting a loop time of around 3ms so you'd be looking at something over 10^19 years for it to complete, or a billion times the age of the universe.

Comment: Cool, will have to try your parallel table. 2nd, I think your final post is talking about listing all twin prime pairs for a given input rather than 1. I wouldn't need to test anything that large. My goal would be to simply see whether their quantity increases as input increases. For instance, would prime 10 create more twin primes than 7? Prime 7 more than prime 4? etc.

Comment: Also, When reverse engineering those twin primes down to their -2+2-4+4 factors, I'm noticing that $p$ is often squared. Perhaps the prime product is including it the 2nd time, i.e. where it should say $<p$ it's allowing $<=p$?

Comment: And a possible speedup, right not it's checking primes in the prime product starting at $p$ and working down. What if the prime product were populated starting at $7$ and working up? That would allow it to work with smaller numbers, and thus be faster in theory right?

Comment: Yes `p` was included twice in the original code - once in `primesList` and again explicitly in `twinPrimes`. 5 also appears in both. You can remove both of those from `primesList` and also work from small numbers up by changing the range in `primesList` to `Range[PrimePi[p-1], 4, -1]`

Comment: Working great! I had been using "`AbsoluteTiming[out = List[]; 
 For[j = 15000, j <= 15100, j = j + 1, 
  out = out~Append~{j, Prime[j], testPrime[Prime[j], 1]}]; 
 out // TableForm]`" to test long lists, but yours is much faster. It however doesn't give the 3 columns that this does. Any way to use yours and still get the 3 collumns like this http://imgur.com/Eg9w8Vu with prime number, prime, and twin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35840/discussion-between-user3363795-and-simon-woods).

Comment: Here's what I'm shooting for now. Abby help in this direction? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660283/pattern-in-twin-primes